# Swift update tableViewCell when nested child in snapshot is updated/added

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I have a **db** in **firebase** as follows:
[image]

I have made a **tableViewController** in which the **cells** will display the **partnerID** as well as **users.count**

This is the code that I have written:

```
Database.database().reference().child("colleges").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
            let user = User()
            if let partnerID = dict["partnerID"] as? String {
                user.name = partnerID
            }
            if let samples = dict["users"] as? NSDictionary {
                user.count = samples.count
            }
            self.userList.append(user)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })
```

When a **new user** is added to the **'users' child**, the **user.count** in the  tableViewCell **doesn't get updated**.

How do I change the code to update the code to make this possible?

Comment: observe .value instead of . childAdded

Comment: @NishantBhindi the userList will append the same objects when a new child is added to the 'users' db in this case. How to avoid that?

Comment: in observer block first remove all objects of userList and then append.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with Nishant's help.

Here's the updated code:

```
Database.database().reference().child("colleges").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        self.userList.removeAll()
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:NSDictionary] {
            for college in dict {
                let user = User()
                if let partnerID = college.value["partnerID"] as? String {
                    user.name = partnerID
                }
                if let samples = college.value["users"] as? NSDictionary {
                    user.count = samples.count
                }
                self.userList.append(user)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    })
```